# Php contact forms

Tags: php, forms

I am working on a contact form. Now I am having a problem when the user is suppose to re enter the password it doesnt work. I know this is probaly something small but I havent been able to figure it out. Here is my code:

```
<?php
function showForm($strMessage){
echo "<h1>".$strMessage."</h1>";
echo " <p>Note: fields marked with '*' are required</p>\n";
echo "<form action=\"".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."\" method=\"post\">\n";
echo "<table width=\"45%\" class=\"formtable\" cellpadding=\"3\" cellspacing=\"0\">\n";
echo "  <tr>\n";
echo "      <td><span id=\"rfvname\">* Name:</span></td>\n";
echo "      <td><input type=\"text\" name=\"name\"   value=\"".$_POST['name']."\" /></td>\n";
echo "  </tr>\n";
echo "    <tr>\n";
echo "      <td><span id=\"rfvemail\">* E-mail:</span></td>\n";
echo "      <td><input type=\"text\" name=\"email\" value=\"".$_POST['emial']."\" /></td>\n";
echo "  </tr>\n";
echo "      <tr>\n";
echo "      <td><span id=\"rfvusername\">* Username:</span></td>\n";
echo "      <td><input type=\"text\" name=\"username\" value=\"".$_POST['username']."\" /></td>\n";
echo "  </tr>\n";
echo "  <tr>\n";
echo "        <td><span id=\"rfvpword\">* Password:</span></td>\n";
echo "        <td><input type=\"password\" name=\"pword\" value=\"".$_POST['pword']."\" /><br /><span style=\"font-size:9px;\"><em>(at least 4 chars) </em></span></td>\n";
echo "  </tr>\n";
echo "    <tr>\n";
echo "      <td><span id=\"rfvpword\">* Re-enter Password:</span></td>\n";
echo "      <td><input type=\"text\" name=\"pword\" value=\"".$_POST['pword']."\" /></td>\n";
echo "  </tr>\n";
echo "  <tr>\n";
echo "         <td>&nbsp;</td>\n";
echo "         <td><input type=\"submit\" value=\"Submit\" class=\"btnSubmit\" id=\"btnSubmit\" name=\"submit\" /></td>\n";
echo "  </tr>\n";
echo "</table>\n";
echo "</form>\n";
  }
  ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<title>Contact Form</title>
<style type="text/css">
body{
            background-color:#FFBD40;
            color:#000000;
            font-size:100%;
            font-family:Georgia,Verdana,"Times New Roman",sans-serif;
        }


#container{
            background:#FFF573;
            width:800px;
            margin:auto;
            padding:5px 10px 5px 10px;
            border:6px double #000000;
        }
</style>
   </head>
    <body>
    <div id="container">
     <?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if (trim($_POST['name'])==""){
        $strMessage="Please enter your name!";
        showForm($strMessage);
    }
    elseif (strlen(trim($_POST['pword']))<=3){
        $strMessage="Your password must be at least 4 characters long!";
        showForm($strMessage);
    }
    else{
         $strMessage="Thank you, your information has been submitted. Below is the information you sent:";
         $strMessageBody.="Name: ".trim(stripslashes($_POST['name']))."<br />";
         $strMessageBody.="E-mail: ".trim(stripslashes($_POST['email']))."<br />";
         $strMessageBody.="UserName: ".trim(stripslashes($_POST['username']))."<br />";
         $strMessageBody.="Password: ".trim(stripslashes($_POST['pword']))."<br />";
        echo "<h1>".$strMessage."</h1>";
        echo $strMessageBody;
    }
       }
     else{
    $strMessage= "Please fill out the form below to send your information:";
    showForm($strMessage);
    }
       ?>
     </div>
      </body>
      </html>
```

Comment: and so, doesn't work means...what exactly in this case?  What are you getting as opposed to what you are expecting?

Comment: i dont think both password fields should have the same name "pword"

Comment: Need more description of the problem. What isn't working and how do you want it to work? In general, I wouldn't fill the password field in again for them. If the user wants the browser to save their password, they can, but don't put it back into the password field from your $_POST variable. Additionally, use type="passwword" for that input type, not text.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Maybe a message or a vague clue as to what the problem is. Either a console error message or an error logfile message  are add-ons that could help?

Comment: Yeah i dont think i want it to save the password and when you push the submit button if you didnt re-enter the password it should ask you to do it again and it doesnt.

Comment: @Adithya +1'ed for having the patience to wade through that and find. This code, although not bad at all as totally close to running php code could be refactored into a lot more concise classes and/or functions.

Comment: Remove the value attribute for the password fields entirely then - the user is going to provide those for you (and change the type while you're at it.) As to how you're validating, what does your current validation code look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you request for 2 passwords for the sake of comparison you should give them different names; otherwise the second input will overwrite the first and you only get 1 value.

Here's how you'd go about validating your passwords:

```
if (trim($_POST['name'])==""){
    $strMessage="Please enter your name!";
    showForm($strMessage);
}
/* START ADD */
elseif ($_POST['pword1'] != $_POST['pword2']) {
    $_POST['pword1'] = NULL;  // Reset the values of pword1 so it is not in the form
    $_POST['pword2'] = NULL;  // Reset the values of pword2 so it is not in the form
    $strMessage="Passwords do not match!";
    showForm($strMessage);
}
/* END ADD */
elseif (strlen(trim($_POST['pword']))<=3){
    $strMessage="Your password must be at least 4 characters long!";
    showForm($strMessage);
}
else ...
```

Comment: Ok if the user didnt have the same password i need something that pops up saying please enter the same password how would i code that?

Comment: I am a little confused how to do that would it be something like  global $errors; for each( $errors as $err){ech $err, "<br>"; } But I am not quite understanding it.

Answer (score 1):

You can give the 're-type password' field to another name like

```
echo "      <td><span id=\"rfvpword\">* Re-enter Password:</span></td>\n";
echo "      <td><input type=\"text\" name=\"repword\" value=\"".$_POST['repword']."\" /></td>\n";
```

then at the validation part put in one more elseif to check is it matching the password or not

```
elseif ($_POST['repword'] != $_POST['pword']){
    $strMessage="Re-type password must be same as password!";
    showForm($strMessage);
}
```

Havent tested the code, just a roughly idea, hope it helps you